# how to read in only an int and ignore the rest in C++

Tags: c++

For example say I have these lines of data from an .txt file that looks like this:

```
43-.u87t 24days r random sentence 
54pj6fcb5 22things L random sentence
```

I need to get the 43 ignore the rest of that then get the 24 ignore days, get the r then get the string then do it again with the next line.

i will eventually get this info into an output file where 43 would be an ascII character used as a fill character, 24 would be the width of the output string, r would equal right justification and the string just gets put in. so the output for line 1 would be:

```
+++++++++random sentence
```

line 2 would be:

```
random sentence6666666
```

This isn't my exact assignment but pretty similar. right now i have this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
string filename;
int a, b, c; // ASCII values for fill character
int aw, bw, cw; // width values for setwidth
char x, y, z; // character for right or left justification
string s1, s2, s3; // strings

ifstream inData;

cout << "please enter the location of the file you wish to input: " << endl;
getline(cin, filename);

inData.open(filename.c_str());


    inData >>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have written a wrapper round nothing!

Comment: Are you familiar with stringstream?

Comment: There's this awesome post from [Ivan Neeson](http://www.kumobius.com/2013/08/c-string-to-int/) that show different ways to convert `string` to `int`. Some of them has the behavior you want.

Comment: Beta: no I'm not familiar with stringstream yet.  wendelbsilva ok I will check them out thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`(\d*).*? (\d*).*? (\w) .*`

The above regex returns three matched groups. (tested using Rad Regex Designer http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/)

“43-.u87t 24days r random sentence” gives “43”, “24”, and “r”

“54pj6fcb5 22things L random sentence” gives “54”, “22”, and “L”

I do not have C++ environments, but boost regex can do the job for you given the above pattern.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried it but can't get any productive results from it. I'm still too new to understand exactly whats happening with that thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading every single char and check with isdigit() if it is a number.
If you detect a number, put it in a string until isdigit() is false. Then convert the string to a number.

mfg

Answer (score 0):

menrfa beat me to it.

Nevertheless, have you considered using a regular expression?

I wrote a quick program that makes use of one to parse your two sample sentences:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main ()
{
    std::smatch sm;
    std::regex r("(\\d*).*? (\\d*).*? (\\w) (.*)");
    std::string s[2] = {"43-.u87t 24days r random sentence",
                        "54pj6fcb5 22things L random sentence"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        std::regex_match(s[i], sm, r);    
        std::cout << "The first number matched is  : " << sm[1] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "The second number matched is : " << sm[2] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "The character matched is     : " << sm[3] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "The sentence matched is      : " << sm[4] << std::endl
                  << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
The first number matched is  : 43
The second number matched is : 24
The character matched is     : r
The sentence matched is      : random sentence

The first number matched is  : 54
The second number matched is : 22
The character matched is     : L
The sentence matched is      : random sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get each line of your input with `std::getline()`. You can then use an `istringstream` on that line to parse each component of your input as textual elements up to the first byte of your random sentence. Getting this first byte allows `istringstream` to skip the leading whitespace up to your sentence. You can then put back that byte and then get the rest of the input as your random sentence.

The first two strings can then be parsed (again with `istringstream`) for the integer values that you want.

```
int main () {
    std::string line, first, second, sentence;
    char just, byte;
    int fill, width;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        if (iss >> first >> second >> just >> byte) {
            iss.putback(byte);
            std::getline(iss, sentence);
            std::istringstream(first) >> fill;
            std::istringstream(second) >> width;
            //...
        } else {
            std::cerr << "invalid input: " << line << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Follow this [link](http://ideone.com/fPFAsA) for a demonstration of the above code.